# How to run same test on multiple urls like 100s of them using selenium ( Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium. Currently, I am working on creating a program that will test multiple report url in browser using selenium.

Scenario: xml file will have multiple url declaration.There will be separate property file for login details. main java program will read xml file and run test using selenium one by one using. If test case passed send an email notification and if it fails also send email notification. Email will have detailed report like which  url failed or passed.

Currently my program is able to read multiple urls and perform the testing. Can anyone suggest me high level overiew on how can I achieve the above scenario in the best way possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TestNG framework where you can take help of dataproviders.
create a method to read data from xml and return in 2d data and declare this method as dataprovider. testNG provides the flexibility of using this dataprovider in parallel which comes in handy while running your test